# Abaqus Python and Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, abaqus

I would like to use the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) python module inside Abaqus CAE 2018 on a Windows 7 machine.

I am able to load and use it with the 2017 version using the package `win-64/pandas-0.10.1-np16py27_0.tar.bz2` from [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas/files?version=0.10.1).

If I use the exact same package with 2018, on `import pandas`, it returns this error:

[image: MSVCR90 error]

I have installed:

- Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable
- Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable
- Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable
- Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable
- Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable
- Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7

but still same error.

I tried to add to the `PATH` an existing folder with that library in it but I get a different error:

[image: Error]

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Reading the requirements for Abaqus, seems that they moved from Visual Studio 2012 to 2015 moving from 2017 to 2018.